# Safari doesn't render variables until highlighted

Tags: angularjs

There's a strange issue I've come across that I can't really explain. I've tried all manners of `ng-cloak`'ing and fiddling with the digest and applying and nothing has solved it.

Basically, when a person on a safari browser comes on my AngularJS App (on certain pages) the variables in that `<div>` do not show at all until highlighted:

[image: Strange safari issues.]

Can anyone shed some light on this strange issue; on other browsers it is completely fine.

Here's what the view looks like:

```html
<div class="tbp-15">
  <h3 class="dark mt-5">
    {{Job.quote.Brand.name}} {{Job.quote.Product.name}} {{Job.quote.selectedKw}}kW
  </h3>
  <p class="light-grey mt-5">
    {{Job.quote.Warranty}} Year Warranty,
    <span ng-repeat="Perk in Job.quote.Perks | filter: notNullBrand">
      {{Perk.Brand.name}} {{Perk.Product.name}}
      <span ng-hide="$last">, </span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="tbp-15 t-light-border arrow-bg">
  <h2 class="dark mb-5">
    {{Job.quote.Price | currency: "£" : 2}} / {{getPackageMonthlyPrice(Job.quote.Price, Job.quote.Finance.selectedYear, Job.quote.Finance.selectedAPR, Job.quote.Finance.selectedDeposit) | currency: "£" : 2}}pm
  </h2>
</div>
```

Also, I'd like to point out that the console shows no errors/ warnings on this page.

Comment: post some of your code first. Could it be a CSS issue?

Comment: Woops! Forgot to paste it in. Will do now.

Comment: I have added the HTML view code.

Comment: This is surely a bug in Safari. Similar problems have arisen in the past (i.e., https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16319 ). I would advise you to look for related webkit bug reports.